# Wordpress - Wrapping posts in same category with <section>

Tags: php, wordpress, reveal.js

I am trying to use Reveal.js (https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/) on WordPress with the Posts being the content per each slide.

I have gotten the post to display properly on the slides, but I am having trouble finding a way to wrap posts that have the same category in a  tag.

Basically, My current code looks something like this:

```
<section class="section  chapter-1 ">
</section>
<section class="section  chapter-1 ">
</section>
<section class="section  chapter-1 ">
</section>

<section class="section  chapter-2 ">
</section>
<section class="section  chapter-2 ">
</section>
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
<section id="category-1">
 <section class="section  chapter-1 ">
 </section>
 <section class="section  chapter-1 ">
 </section>
 <section class="section  chapter-1 ">
 </section>
</section>

<section id="category-2">
 <section class="section  chapter-2 ">
 </section>
 <section class="section  chapter-2 ">
 </section>
</section>
```

Here is my index.php code:

```
<div class="reveal content-area">
 <div id="content" class="slides site-content" role="main">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php /* The loop */ ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>
  <?php else : ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
 </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

... and so on with more 'chapters' and more categories

If you notice the second code example are grouped and wrapped in a section tag with an ID of the category name.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this, or have an array with categories

```
<?php
$args = array( 'category' => 1 );
get_posts($args);
?>
<section id="category-1">
<?php
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
 <section class="section  chapter-<?php the_ID()?> ">
    the_content();
 </section>
<?php
endwhile; endif;
?>
</section>
<?php
wp_reset_query();

$args = array( 'category' => 2 );
get_posts($args);
<section id="category-2">
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
 <section class="section  chapter-<?php the_ID()?> ">
    the_content();
 </section>
endwhile; endif;
</section>
wp_reset_query();
?>
```